# Rewrap text wrapped with wrong marks/brackets

Tags: javascript, plugins, refactoring, atom-editor, editing

I need some help. I'm using Atom as ide and I need to rewrap some texts with other characters in order to fix a bunch of typos in a code.

Example:

```
"text1":"text2"
```

has to become

```
foo['text1'] = "text2"
```

I Just need to rewrap a word with other things of my choice obviously keeping the original word inside it. 
Does anyone knows a plugin for Atom or NPP or any text editor that could do at least something similar?

**Question:**

**Does anyone knows how to do this with a regex instead?**
I think it is a pretty common mistake to fix.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Is doing a replaceAll `"text1":` -> `foo['text1'] = ` not efficient enough for this scenario?

Comment: It could be efficient just for one single mistake, but if I have multiple things to fix with different contents, it couldn't work. The ideal solution is something that does not care about the content at all.